# Conditional formatting with color and icon for table in print layout

Tags: qgis, symbology, attribute-table, qgis-print-layouts, conditional

I used the conditional formatting option in the attribute table (figure 01) in QGIS 3.12.

[image]

I created a layout with the map and the attributes table (figure 02). With the option “apply layer conditional styling colors" (figure 03). But the icon (symbol) did not appear in the table.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Conditional formatting in the map layout attribute table supports only [font colour and cell background](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#feature-allow-layout-attribute-tables-to-be-styled-using-the-foreground-and-background-colors-of-matching-conditional-styles) for now (v 3.12). I am not sure this will be expanded in 3.14

Comment: You need to open a feature request in github so that this won’t be forgotten or anyone with coding skills can help

Comment: I opened a feature request.